# Change Icon on button press

Tags: react-native

I am using an Icon 'caret-down' from FontAwesome for drop-down but when I click on drop-down I want to show Icon 'caret-up' can anyone please help me with this. Please find the below code.

```
<View>
      <Button
            title="Advance Profile"
            onButtonClick={() => {
              setShowAdvanceProfile((showAdvanceProfile) => {
                return !showAdvanceProfile;
              });
            }}
      />
      <Icon name='caret-down' size={20} color='white' />
 </View>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change icon(icon name properties) on button after clicking on button that is onPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096803/how-to-change-iconicon-name-properties-on-button-after-clicking-on-button-that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a state variable saying whether the arrow should be up or down. Here's a simplified example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [arrowUp, setArrowUp] = React.useState(false) // <--- here
  
  const setShowAdvanceProfile = () => {}

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
            title="Advance Profile"
            onPress={() => {
              setArrowUp(!arrowUp); // <--- here
              setShowAdvanceProfile((showAdvanceProfile) => {
                return !showAdvanceProfile;
              }); 
            }}
      />
      <Text>{arrowUp ? "carat-up" : "carat-down"}</Text> // <--- here
      
 </View>
  );
}
```

Working example: `https://snack.expo.io/RahpIEkF_`

This is a little different than yours, since I had to mock `setShowAdvanceProfile` -- I also used `Text` instead of `Icon` since I didn't have `Icon` to use in the snack, but the principal will be the same for you:

```
 <Icon name={arrowUp ? 'carat-up' : 'caret-down'} size={20} color='white' />
```

I also used `onPress` instead of your `onButtonClick` which is the default handler for React Native's `Button`, but perhaps you're using a different component.

Finally, this will look a little different if you're using class components rather than function components. You'll end up calling something like:

```
this.setState({arrowUp: true})
```

instead of my `setArrowUp` call. I can update my answer if you're using class components and this bit ends up confusing.

Comment: I am using function component